# Segmentation fault when trying to read stdin to a 2d dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm trying to read from stdin to a dynamic array of strings, using spaces as separators. The code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char** parseInput(size_t *numElements)
{
  char **lines;
  int outerIndex = 0;
  int innerIndex = 0;
  int widths = 1;
  char c=getchar();
  lines =(char**) malloc((outerIndex+1)*sizeof(char*));
  lines[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
  while(c!=EOF)
  {
    if(innerIndex==widths)//reallocate each strings length, double it
    {
      widths+=widths;
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<outerIndex+1;i++)
        lines[i]=(char*)realloc(lines[i],(widths+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
    lines[outerIndex][innerIndex]=c;
    innerIndex++;
    if(c==' ')//allocate memory for the next string in the array of strings
    {
      lines[outerIndex][innerIndex]='\0';
      innerIndex=0;
      outerIndex++;
      lines =(char**) realloc(lines,(outerIndex+1)*sizeof(char*));
      lines[outerIndex] = (char*) realloc(lines[outerIndex],(widths+1)*sizeof(char));
      //the above line in the debugger causes a segfault when outerIndex=19
    }
    c=getchar();
  }
  if(innerIndex!=0)//if the last character is not a space, append a space
  {
    if(innerIndex==widths)
    {
      widths+=widths;
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<outerIndex+1;i++)
        lines[i]=(char*)realloc(lines[i],(widths+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
    lines[outerIndex][innerIndex]=' ';
    lines[outerIndex][innerIndex+1]='\0';
  }
  *numElements=(size_t)(outerIndex+1);
  return lines;
}
int main()
{
    size_t num =0;
    char** lines = parseInput(&num);
}
```

When the outer array size grows to anything more than 20 variables, I get a segmentation fault at the indicated line. For example the following input causes a segfault

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

but the following does not

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

The debug error says

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003417e7bf4d in realloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

What could this be caused by?

Comment: I'm sorry for earlier, I've pasted, compiled, and ran, this is the code as it is and the error still occurs.

Comment: You would do well to learn how to use GDB. Here is a decent link http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_toc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
lines[outerIndex] = (char*) realloc(lines[outerIndex], (widths+1)*sizeof(char));
```

you supply an uninitialized pointer as the first argument to `realloc`. You should probably use `malloc` here instead.

Other issues:

- `char c` should be `int c` (read the documentation for `getchar` to see why).
- If the input begins with a space then `lines[outerIndex][innerIndex]='\0'` writes out of bounds.
- The code block starting `if(innerIndex==widths)` is repeated twice in your code; it would be better to either make this a function, or restructure your code so there is not this repetition.
- You can simplify your malloc/realloc calls by removing redundant casts and the redundant multiplication by `sizeof(char)` which is always `1`.
- You should check malloc/realloc for failure and act accordingly.

Comment: also, don't call realloc like this.  when it fails, you have lost the original pointer to the memory.  Save the result of realloc to a temporary variable and assign it on success.

Comment: Thank you, initializing line[outerIndex] = NULL; prior to the realloc statement seemed to fix the error.